# Enable integrated SMTP notification vs. self-made hooks

Tags: git, gitolite, gitlab

first of all I am really excited about such a powerful solution to manage users and projects via web-application when using gitlab.

I finished my installation and added my smpt settings to the file config/production.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address => 'myserver.com',
 :port => 25,
 :domain => 'gitlab.adomain.com',
 :authentication => :plain,
 :user_name => 'gitlab@myserver.com',
 :password => '',
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
```

Additionally, I changed the file config/gitlab.yml:

```
email:
from: account@myserver.com
…
```

The SMTP settings are checked and work properly with other applications. I restarted the gitlab-server expecting notifications would be send when adding a user to a project or even if commits are propagated to the remote without using selfmade hooks. But they aren't.

This is the output of my webinterface:

```
     gitserver:3254 on mailer at 2 minutes ago

Class
    Notify
Arguments

    "project_access_granted_email"
    31    
Exception
    Net::SMTPAuthenticationError
Error
    502 Command "AUTH PLAIN <tokenid>" not implemented
```

These are my questions:

1. In my resque overview there is a queue called mailer with 1 active (mail)jobs which doesn't complete. Below there is an information that no workers are currently working. How can I handle this?
2. I want to implement post-receive hooks to send mails if gitlab turns out to be unable  to manage this. How do I configure my postfix for that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your GitLab version, but the latest one doesn't seem to work well with the Resque workers (including the [resque mailer](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/813)):
See [issue 2472](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2472):

```
# bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=post_receive,mailer,system_hook RAILS_ENV=production PIDFILE=tmp/pids/resque_worker.pid
Starting worker git1-0:7710:post_receive,mailer,system_hook
Registered signals
Running before_first_fork hooks with [#<Worker git1-0:7710:post_receive,mailer,system_hook>]
#~
```

You can check that way if there is at least one process (managing/sending emails) running in your case.

The Issue mentioned has the current resolution of updating redis, because of an obsolete version:

> as root - on stable debian

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server stop
cd /tmp
wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.2.4.tar.gz
cd redis-2.2.4
make PREFIX=/usr
make install PREFIX=/usr
/etc/init.d/redis-server start
```

> edit the `init.d` script and remove `PIDFILE=` from resque command.
>   After the start command of `resque` add the following

```
ps auxww|grep QUEUE=post|head -n1|awk '{print $2}' > $RESQUE_PID
```

> so the `pidfile` is created - this fixes the "stop" error
>
> `stop/start gitlab` - push and your fine

Comment: Hmmm. The command doesn't produce any output at all. As I can see there are four PostReceive jobs pending but not processed.  #Workers (shown in web-interface)=0.

Comment: @JohnRumpel strange, there should be one mailer worker active. It is either a configuration issue, or a GitLab bug.

Comment: I added a the output of the webinterface resque section to my question, maybe it helps to identify the problem